# How to change autofill groups name in res.users odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I made new security in the custom module, like this

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="module_create">
  <field name="name">Module Role</field>
  <field name="description">User access level for this module</field>
  <field name="sequence">5</field>
</record>
<record id="group_merc" model="res.groups">
  <field name="name">Merc Access</field>
  <field name="category_id" ref="mymodule.module_create"/>
  <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

and i make another form views using class *res.users* like this

```
<page name="access_rights" string="Access Rights">
                            <field name="groups_id" widget="many2many_tags" options='{"no_create": True, "no_open": True}'/>
                        </page>
```

the field displays like this
[image]
can i remove the fields views and change of the form in groups_id by displaying the group names that I have created automatically without having to do a search first?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you explain what is wrong with what it displayed by default? And what you want it to display instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `many2many_checkboxes` which will list all the groups and you can select without any searching required.

```
<field name="groups_id" widget="many2many_checkboxes" />
```